# data (with eval) as arguments to jquery-method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, arguments

I'm using "eval" to fetch data from an db and place it in my application (adding and deleting contacts). When deleting a contact a confirm box is shown which works fine.

However, what I want is to use the data (from eval) as arguments to the js function, so that I can show the contacts name in the confirm box.

Below is the code, which doesn't work. What can I write to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

```
<asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
<asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
<asp:Button ID="EditLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CausesValidation="False" />
<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="return confirmOnDelete(<%# Eval("FirstName") %>, <%# Eval("LastName") %>);" />
```

from the js-file:

```
    confirmOnDelete: function (firstName, lastName) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure that you want to delete " + firstName + " " + lastName + " ?") == true) {
            alert("tog bort");
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe you just need to quote your arguments. `confirmOnDelete('...', '...')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle it from jQuery level.

```
<asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /> 
<asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /> 
<asp:Button ID="EditLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CausesValidation="False" /> 
<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="return confirmOnDelete();" />
```

Then for your script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmOnDelete() {
        var firstName = $("[id*=FirstNameLabel]").text();
        var lastName = $("[id*=LastNameLabel]").text();
        var decision = confirm("Are you sure that you want to delete " + firstName + " " + lastName + " ?")
        return (decision)
    }
</script>
```

If this is part of a nested process let me know because it won't work (i.e. the two labels are inside a repeater or something).  Then we need to adjust it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery to capture this button and dynamically create the message

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var updateButtons = $('#<%= theGridViewID.ClientID %> :button[value=Delete]');
    updateButtons.each(function () {
        var onclick = $(this).attr('onclick');
        $(this).attr('onclick', null).click(function () {
            // find the previus two divs and get the name of the user
            // then create the question    
            var doPostBack = confirm("Delete this user? This action cannot be undone...");
            if (doPostBack)
               return onclick();
            else
               return false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried that, but I get the following error message: "The server tag is not well formed."

Comment: @JasonCraig I have update the question, I only left for you to find the user name - the two previous div.